# Windows 8 App - Programmatically Added Path Disappears

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

I am trying to build an app in Windows 8 using xaml and vb.

To test the process of adding a path dynamically to the UI I have created a class that draws a circle using a path (code below). The code fires when a button is tapped/clicked.

The circle then appears briefly near the centre of the screen but then disappears.

If I then count the children on the grid, the circle is counted. Its just not visible.

I'd like to understand what is happening and stop the circle from disappearing.

```
Dim path As New Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path
Dim rectG As New EllipseGeometry
rectG.Center = New Point(500, 500)
rectG.RadiusX = 100
rectG.RadiusY = 100
path.Data = rectG
path.Stroke = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGreen)
path.StrokeThickness = 1
path.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGreen)
path.Name = "TestName"
_TargetGrid.Children.Add(path)
```

Comment: there's some other contributing factor.  I copied and pasted your code behind a button on a simple form, and it works just fine.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you, Jim. I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: Hi @Jim, I've created a new project and imported the class. Same problem. The key is that it appears _behind_ the parent grid. It's here I'm misunderstanding something. Some of the circle appears between the gap of "My Application" and the mainGrid, which I target. Here is a screenshot [link](http://i1353.photobucket.com/albums/q673/cgrady1/SS1_zps0c1a6cb5.png)

Comment: Finally, got it. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I needed to set the column and row span property.

On the test I did it using the code although in a proper app it would probably make sense to use some kind of predetermined styling.

However, here is the code I added:

```
path.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 5)
path.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 5)
```